# SqlDependency simple select query always returns "Invalid"

Tags: c#, sql, service-broker, sqldependency

I'm trying to get the SqlDependency object to give me notifications, but so far I'm not able to get it working.

the sql query that I'm sending is this:

```
SELECT [SocialMedia].[dbo].[Items].[Id]
  FROM [SocialMedia].[dbo].[Items]
```

I've tried it w/ and w/o the braces, having the fully qualified name, having only the variable name, and everything inbetween.

Id is of type `Guid` which I didn't see any mention that they didn't work with SqlDependency objects in the [Creating a Query for Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx) article

I've also tried sending multiple columns over to see if that would work.

```
  SELECT SocialMedia.dbo.Items.Id, 
         SocialMedia.dbo.Items.DateTimeCreated, 
         SocialMedia.dbo.Items.AuthorId
  FROM   SocialMedia.dbo.Items
```

And that also didn't work.

---

## Here is my table SQL:

```
USE [SocialMedia]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [DateTimeCreated] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [AuthorId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Source] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [PlaceId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [FullText] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Geography] [geography] NULL,
    [DateTimeAdded] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC ) 
                 WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                 IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                 ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Places] 
FOREIGN KEY([PlaceId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Places] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Places]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Users] 
FOREIGN KEY([AuthorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Users]
```

## And my DB:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [SocialMedia]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
 ( NAME = N'SocialMedia', 
   FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.DENALI\MSSQL\DATA\SocialMedia.mdf' , 
    SIZE = 1110016KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'SocialMedia_log', 
  FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.DENALI\MSSQL\DATA\SocialMedia_log.ldf' , 
  SIZE = 123648KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
GO

IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')) BEGIN
  EXEC [SocialMedia].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'enable'
END
GO

ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET ANSI_NULL_DEFAULT OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET ANSI_PADDING ON 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET ARITHABORT ON 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET AUTO_SHRINK OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS ON 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET CURSOR_DEFAULT  GLOBAL 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET  ENABLE_BROKER 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET DATE_CORRELATION_OPTIMIZATION OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET RECOVERY FULL 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET  MULTI_USER 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET PAGE_VERIFY CHECKSUM  
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET DB_CHAINING OFF 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET FILESTREAM( NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = OFF ) 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET TARGET_RECOVERY_TIME = 0 SECONDS 
ALTER DATABASE [SocialMedia] SET  READ_WRITE
```

## And the code I'm using to run it:

```
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open(); // open new connection and create command to notify about all new Chat-Messages in -ROOM_NUMBER- const
using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(GetSearchQueryString(searchItems), conn))
{
    var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(sqlCommand
    //handle onChange event - this will be fired whenever there is a change in database that affacts our query
    sqlDependency.OnChange += (sender, e) =>
    {
        //change detected - get all messages...
        try
        {

            var sql = GetSearchQueryString(searchItems);
            int count = _entities.ExecuteStoreQuery<Guid>(sql).Count();

            AsyncManager.Parameters["count"] = count;
        }
        finally
        {
            AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
        }
    };
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I'm calling `SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString);` earlier in the program.

Am I missing something?  I feel I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Perhaps try not disposing the SqlCommand object?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? can you post the error?

Comment: Have you done all of the necessary setup on the server side? (enabling clr integration and the service broker, setting permissions etc.)

Comment: @usr - Does not work means I get an immediate response with the status member variable of the EventArgs set to "Invalid". :/ No error message, no nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We followed the steps described in http://dimarzionist.wordpress.com/2009/04/01/how-to-make-sql-server-notifications-work/

Comment: I went through the document step by step and IDK which step it was that I hadn't done, but now it's working!  Thanks for the guide :)

Answer (score 13):

I found SqlDependency to be very fragile. Sometimes, if you do something invalid, you always get a notification immediately. No error message.

Try to remove the database name qualification from the query. Reference the table like this: `dbo.Items`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using three part names, i.e.

`[SocialMedia].[dbo].[Items].[Id]`

The documentation clearly states you need to use two part names, so change to

`[SocialMedia].[Items].[Id]`

Answer (score 1):

Michael's answer is an excellent source, but there's one thing that Microsoft omitted to mention:

> The SQL Broker will reject SELECT statements on a table **that has a
>   computed column**

If you try, you'll get an SqlNotificationEventArgs with info=Query, type=Subscribe, and like me you'll spend hours trying to figure out what's wrong with the statement, when it's the computed column that's the culprit.

Comment: Urgh anyone know of work around for this?  I tried replacing with a view but that doesn't do it either.

Answer (score 0):

Execute in your SQl Server

> ALTER DATABASE YOURDBNAME SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE